# gRPC Streaming with gatling not working with Scala

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

We are trying to test gRPC server streaming with Gatling with Scala

```scala
//-------------------METHOD_EXECUTE_COMMAND ---------------------------
val gmrExecuteCommandRequestStreamCall: ServerStream  = grpc("Server Streaming call").serverStream("gmrExecuteCommandReplier")
```

And we are encountering the below error:

```
[error] /opt/gatling/tests/src/test/scala/testing/SessionServerStreamGRPC.scala:30:44: class ServerStream takes type parameters
[error]    val gmrExecuteCommandRequestStreamCall: ServerStream  = grpc("Server Streaming Call").serverStream("gmrExecuteCommandReplier")
[error]                                            ^
[error] /opt/gatling/tests/src/test/scala/testing/SessionServerStreamGRPC.scala:30:102: not enough arguments for method serverStream: (method: io.grpc.MethodDescriptor[Req,Res], streamName: String): com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.ServerStream[Req,Res].
[error] Unspecified value parameter streamName.
[error]    val gmrExecuteCommandRequestStreamCall: ServerStream  = grpc("Server Streaming Call").serverStream("gmrExecuteCommandReplier")
```

We have already added the below package to support this along with other packages

```scala
import com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request
```

Can someone guide to support the single argument request and get rid of the error?

Tried searching and instrumenting the code additionally but still the same error.

Comment: There seems to be only one method available and it needs two arguments: https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/phisgr/gatling/grpc/request/builders.scala#L16

Answer (score 2):

If you are not familiar with Scala, you should use [Gatling-gRPC with Java/Kotlin](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/tree/master/gatling-grpc-kt).

---

`class ServerStream takes type parameters`

Unlike Java, Scala does not allow the use of raw types (e.g. `List<Thing>` vs `List`). It's square brackets `[]` in Scala instead of angle brackets `<>` though.

---

`not enough arguments for method serverStream`

From the [change log](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0140):

> Streaming method descriptors are moved earlier in the construction, provided at the same time as `streamName`. This change makes it harder to have type errors.

---

So if your protobuf looks like this,

```
service YourService {
    rpc Execute (RequestType) returns (stream ResponseType);
}
```

the correct usage should then be

```scala
val gmrExecuteCommandRequestStreamCall: ServerStream[RequestType, ResponseType] =
  grpc("Server Streaming call")
    .serverStream(YourServiceGrpc.METHOD_EXECUTE, "gmrExecuteCommandReplier")
```

You can refer to the examples [here](https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/phisgr/example/StreamingExample.scala#L41).

---

Where did you see the example with the old method invocation? Why were you unwilling to pass the extra parameter in the new version?