# Type "clientStream" not found in gatling grpc

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

I have continued to investigate on this gatling/grpc, I have put my code together as the below, code definition is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872205/grpc-streaming-with-gatling-not-working-with-scala)

```
class BasicSimu extends Simulation {

  val TokenKey : String = "token-string"
  val grpcConf = grpc(managedChannelBuilder("url:80").usePlaintext())
                .header(util.BearerToken, optional = true)($(TokenKey))
                .shareChannel
  val thisStream: ClientStream [StartPairingRequest, StartPairing Response] = grpc("Speak").clientStream(RelayServerGrpc.METHOD_START_PAIRING, "gettingThePairingKey") 
  val speaker = scenario("BasicSimu")
      .exec(
        thisStream.connect
      )
  setUp( 
    speaker.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(grpcConf)
}
```

Currently, what I am trying to achieve, is to make a stream from a client calls to Server, and then get the data from it. When I do compile, I got this error log:

```
[error] C:\Users\...\BasicSimu.scala:34:19: not found: type ClientStream
[error]   val thisStream: ClientStream[StartPairingRequest, StartPairingResponse] = grpc("Speak").clientStream(RelayServerGrpc.METHOD_START_PAIRING, "gettingThePairingKey")
```

I have also tries with bidiStream method, and the error is similar there too, the code is following phiSgr's example. Below is the proto definition:

```
rpc StartPairing(StartPairingRequest) returns (stream StartPairingResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/pairing"
      body: "*"
    };
```

The METHOD_START_PAIRING generated

```
val METHOD_START_PAIRING: root.io.grpc.MethodDescriptor[package.StartPairingRequest, package.StartPairingResponse] =
    root.io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.newBuilder()
      .setType(root.io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.MethodType.SERVER_STREAMING)
      .setFullMethodName(root.io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.generateFullMethodName("relay.RelayServer", "StartPairing"))
      .setSampledToLocalTracing(true)
      .setRequestMarshaller(root.scalapb.grpc.Marshaller.forMessage[package.StartPairingRequest])
      .setResponseMarshaller(root.scalapb.grpc.Marshaller.forMessage[package.StartPairingResponse])
      .setSchemaDescriptor(root.scalapb.grpc.ConcreteProtoMethodDescriptorSupplier.fromMethodDescriptor(package.javaDescriptor.getServices().get(0).getMethods().get(0)))
      .build()
```

What parameter did I passed wrong in here by any chance ?

Comment: @GeorgeLeung the import statement was following on your ClientStreamingExample.scala, I believe YOUR import statements are enough over there, I do not use external declaration too. 
If ChatGPT was smart I would not want to bother you in anyway, I'm sorry to cause you frustrating, you don't even need to reply this anymore, I will figure it out on my own then.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung just an update that I have to "import com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request._" to make it works.
I will try to see this further, just a suggestion, though I'm in no position to do that, for you to update the document for the bidi and clientStreaming for people.
Thank for your support

Comment: It might be GatlingCorp's goal to allow one to write load tests without knowing Java/Kotlin/Scala, but not mine. If I have to remind the user that "If you want to specify the type, make sure to add the import statement for it", I may as well write a programming book - which I don't have time for.

Comment: If you do release a book, do let me know tho, I will be happy to buy it.

Comment: And your recipe on Medium is good ngl, thanks @GeorgeLeung

Answer (score 0):

Following my question, here is the answer

```
import com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request._
```