# "Java.lang.illegalArgumentException: requirement failed" when casting clientStream, bidiStream in Gatling GRPC

Tags: scala, gatling

Too afraid to ask, but too stoopid to figure it out.

Continue on my journey with Gatling/GRPC, and hopefully someone might find this helpful in the future

Pointing to the bidiStream definition in builders, there is this definition

```
def bidiStream[Req: ClassTag, Res](method: MethodDescriptor[Req, Res], streamName: String): BidiStream[Req, Res] = BidiStream(requestName, method, streamName)
```

Which lead me to this definition, that I believe I have fulfil enough parameters by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872205/grpc-streaming-with-gatling-not-working-with-scala/75880648#75880648).

```
val clientCall: BidiStream[StartPairingRequest, StartPairingResponse] = grpc("Speak").bidiStream(method = RelayServerGrpc.METHOD_START_PAIRING, streamName = "gettingThePairingKey")
```

I got this error log:

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
[error]         at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:324)
[error]         at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.BidiStream.<init>(builders.scala:69)
[error]         at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.BidiStream$.apply(builders.scala:64)
[error]         at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Grpc.bidiStream(builders.scala:20)
[error]         at test.scala.BasicSimu.<init>(BasicSimu.scala:20)
```

The same error content goes with ClientStream too, by my judgement, there could potentially that the option part on the below proto file avoid the method to be understood by compiler

```
rpc StartPairing(StartPairingRequest) returns (stream StartPairingResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      post: "/v1/pairing"
      body: "*"
    };
```

Gatling version: 3.9.0

sbt: 1.7.1

Library version: 0.16.0

So my question right here is that I just want to see the streaming working or not, so do I have to define full action from start to end ? Currently I just put the scenario to connect only.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260531/5363011). `rpc StartPairing(StartPairingRequest) returns (stream StartPairingResponse)` defines a server stream instead of bidirectional stream.